# Unable to create a Bean of ElasticSearch in my Springboot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, opensearch

I am trying to implement elasticsearch (opensearch from AWS) in my project and have tried to create an elasticsearch repository interface by extending ElasticsearchRepository which takes by Product Class object, and has a few standard methods, but I am unable to create a bean of the Repository as well as some controllers which were working fine before adding ES. There are other errors which are now coming in addition -

The error(s) that I am getting -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'searchController' defined in file [/Users/aditkumar/Desktop/iRobot/Projects/Product_Service/ProductService_proxy/target/classes/com/example/productservice_proxy/Controllers/SearchController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'searchService' defined in file [/Users/aditkumar/Desktop/iRobot/Projects/Product_Service/ProductService_proxy/target/classes/com/example/productservice_proxy/services/SearchService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'productSearchRepo' defined in com.example.productservice_proxy.Repositories.ProductSearchRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); No property 'delete' found for type 'Product'; Did you mean 'deleted'
```

I tried to create a config folder which did not help much. Read through various forums and maybe we don't need to create bean specifically in newer versions. I am using Java 17 and Springboot version 3.2.2. I also referred to a similar error answered before, so added a delete method as well but to no avail. Here is how my classes look like -

Product Class -

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Document(indexName = "productservice")
public class Product extends BaseModel{
    private String title;
    private double price;
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Categories category;
    private String imageUrl;
    private Boolean isPublic;
    private int numberOfUnits;
}
```

ProductRepo class (Extends from JPA Repository) -

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepo extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    Product save(Product product); // (save) is a method of JpaRepository (interface)

    Product findProductById(Long Id);
    Product findByPriceBetween(double greaterthan, double lessthan);

    //Product findByProductName(String productName);

    // String findTitleById(Long id);

    List<Product> findByIdIsNotNullOrderByPrice();

    List<Product> findAllByIsPublicFalse();
    List<Product> findByTitleEquals(String title, Pageable pageable);

    void deleteProductById(Long id);
}
```

ProductSearchRepo class extends ElasticsearchRepository -

```
@Repository
public interface ProductSearchRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<Product, Long> {

    Iterable<Product> findAllByTitleEquals(String title);

    @Query("{\n" +
            "  \"query\": {\n" +
            "    \"match\": {\n" +
            "      \"title\": \"?0\"\n" + // Assuming 'title' is a field in your OpenSearch index
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}")
    List<Product> findAllByTitleContaining(String query);
    void deleteProductById(Long id);
}
```

This is the search service where I am using Elasticsearch repository -

```
@Service
public class SearchService {

    private ProductRepo productRepo;

    private ProductSearchRepo productSearchRepo;

    public SearchService(ProductRepo productRepo, ProductSearchRepo productSearchRepo) {
        this.productRepo = productRepo;
        this.productSearchRepo = productSearchRepo;
    }

    public List<Product> searchProducts(String query, int pageNumber, int sizeOfPage,
                                        List<SortParam> sortParamList) {
//        Sort sort = Sort.by("title").descending()
//                .and(Sort.by("price").descending());

        Sort sort;
        if(sortParamList.get(0).getSortType().equals("ASC")) {
            sort = Sort.by(sortParamList.get(0).getParamName());
        } else {
            sort = Sort.by(sortParamList.get(0).getParamName()).descending();
        }

        for(int i = 1; i< sortParamList.size(); i++) {
            if(sortParamList.get(i).getSortType().equals("ASC")) {
                sort = sort.and(Sort.by(sortParamList.get(i).getParamName()));
            } else {
                sort = sort.and(Sort.by(sortParamList.get(i).getParamName())
                        .descending());
            }
        }

        //return productRepo.findByTitleEquals(query, PageRequest.of(pageNumber, sizeOfPage, sort));

        return productSearchRepo.findAllByTitleContaining(query);

    }
}
```

If you want to take a look at Product Model class, here it is -

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Document(indexName = "productservice")
public class Product extends BaseModel{
    private String title;
    private double price;
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Categories category;
    private String imageUrl;
    private Boolean isPublic;
    private int numberOfUnits;
}
```

Major dependencies I added -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-opensearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

The whole project can be accessed from here - https://github.com/RangerAcodes/Product_service

Answer (score 0):

Spring JPA is scanning the package, `ProductSearchRepo` is in this package so it is scanned too and being proxied. This extends `ElasticsearchRepository`, which has a `delete` method and there is no `delete` field in the `Product` entity so it complains in the log:

> Failed to create query for method public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); No property 'delete' found for type 'Product'

You might want to move this repository class from the current base component scan package. This would resolve this I think.

Comment: I tried your advice, and made some changes here and there, but the error did not go away. Now, I have clean installed the dependencies and added the libraries from scratch again, and this is what I am getting now -

`Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataConfiguration$ReactiveRestClientConfiguration': Lookup method resolution failed
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.checkLookupMethods(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:497) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]`